# String array causing app to stop

Tags: android, arrays

Here code begins of one class named as Homepage.java -

This is initial declarations -

```
int j=0,i=0;
String[] fetch_name,fetch_num;
```

Then following block is used to fetch phonebook contacts -

```
Cursor phones1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null );
    while(phones1.moveToNext())
    {
        j=j+1;
    }
    fetch_name = new String[j];
    fetch_num = new String[j];
    while(phones1.moveToNext())
    {
        fetch_name[i]= phones1.getString(phones1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        fetch_num[i] = phones1.getString(phones1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        i =i + 1;
    }
    phones1.close();
```

Now following are methods returning String Array & integer

```
public String[] getfname()
{
    return(fetch_name);
}
public  String[] getfnum()
{
    return(fetch_num);
}
public  int getj()
{
    return(j);
}
```

Now in second class named as Contactss.java code is as follow -

```
public class Contactss extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment 
{
Homepage hp = new Homepage();
Chatss cs = new Chatss();
int k = hp.getj();
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contactss, container, false);
    loadd();
    return v;
}
public void loadd() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String xyz  []= hp.getfnum();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "jhbh" + xyz.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

The above code causing app to stop, no idea why my app is going to stop.
Please help.

Comment: I think MByD has identified the issue, but if he hasn't the please add the error log from `LogCat`

Answer (score 3):

You go through the entire results here:

```
while(phones1.moveToNext())
{
    j=j+1;
}
```

But never reset to the first element again, so you have no more elements in the `Cursor`, and you set nothing in the arrays. You can either move to the first when you are done counting using [`Cursor#moveToFirst()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29), or even better, count using the [`Cursor#getcount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) method.

As a side note, please add [logcat](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) log next time you have a problem, it will make yours (and our) work much easier

Comment: Sorry, log cat is not available, coming to the solution, problem still exist and following statement occuring exception-                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "jhbh" + xyz.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                When i concatinate "xyz.length", exception occur when i don't no exception occurs

Comment: maybe you should check if `xyz` is null

Comment: `if (xyz == null) Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "oh no, xyz is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`